# C# UI automated testing Excel Add In button

Tags: c#, excel, selenium, testing, excel-addins

In our project we've decided to add a button to the Ribbon of Excel. I need to write an automated test that tests the button itself as well as the form it opens once it's clicked (font, color etc). I'm quite new to this as the only testing I've done is on web pages using Selenium so far. Can I use Selenium to test this? If someone could guide me on how to proceed I'd appreciate it as I'm struggling to find information on this online.

Comment: Broken link... Needs to be C#

Comment: Found something called Windows App Driver? Thinking about investigating that so I may use it.

Comment: Is your tests are Data Driven Apache POI is the most commonly used API for Selenium data driven tests,POI API helps you for reading data from excel, or you may use winium automation framework for Windows platforms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used WinAppDriver to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Selenium is webbased, and what you need is a tool that can work in desktop UIs.

I suggest you look into

- [Coded UI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/use-ui-automation-to-test-your-code?view=vs-2017) or
- [Winium](https://github.com/2gis/Winium) :
  Automation framework for Windows platforms. It is opensource and it is Selenium-based.

Comment: Great, thanks for the info. Have you heard of something called Windows App Driver? Looks promising and seems to be similar to Selenium testing.